# Scroll 2 (or more) tableViews at once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on a very interesting project and I want to expand it.

I have a new feature which I want to include and it needs some tableViews on one view. But now, they're side by side to each other and they need to scroll at the same time to the same point.

How can I do this? *I didn't found any Delegate-methods or properties.*

Thanks in advance,
mavrick3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

on one table when you detect scrolling on the other with the delegate method

`scrollViewDidScroll:` or maybe some of the other members of `UIScrollViewDelegate`